# How to subclass a renamed class? / 'MKPinAnnotationView' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: renamed to 'MKMarkerAnnotationView‘

Tags: ios, swift, conditional-compilation, availability

`MKPinAnnotationView` was renamed in iOS 15 to `MKMarkerAnnotationView`.
Up to iOS 14, I subclassed `MKPinAnnotationView` as

```
class MyAnnotationView: MKPinAnnotationView {
// …
}
```

The problem:
If my app is compiled to iOS 14, I want to declare `MyAnnotationView` as above.
However if it is compiled to iOS 15, I have to use

```
class MyAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
// …
}
```

How can this be achieved?

On the instruction level, I could use something like

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
// iOS 15
} else {
// iOS 14
}
```

But on the class level, apparently only something like

```
@available(iOS 15, *)
class MyAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
```

seems to be available that lets me compile a class if iOS 15 is available, but apparently I cannot avoid compilation of `class MyAnnotationView: MKPinAnnotationView {` if iOS 15 is available.

So how is this handled in Swift?

Comment: Upvoted. Commenting because I want to know the answer. My issue involves using something that became available starting iOS14 - and my apps require iOS 12. The only answer I had was to create *two* subclasses, which this may help me to resolve it using something **better** what you've found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by *@Paulw11* in other answer, `MKMarkerAnnotationView` has been available since `iOS 11`. So there's no need to be on `iOS 15` to use it.

---

This part is still relevant to other cases like *@dfd* mentioned for image picker on `iOS 14` and earlier versions.

---

Not as pretty as it should be, it's worth a shot anyway.

```
import MapKit

#if canImport(CoreLocationUI) // Hack for iOS 15?
public typealias BaseAnnotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView
#else
public typealias BaseAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView
#endif

class MyAnnotationView: BaseAnnotationView {
    
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it will work (sounds like it should) but upvoted your answer like I just did the question. I'll give it a shot with my issue involving the new image picker introduced in iOS 14. Yes, a hack, but much better than littering your code with conditionals based on which iOS version the user is using. Hope it works for the OP!

Comment: Although a hack, it solves the general problem (+1).

Answer (score 2):

`MKPinAnnotationView` hasn't been renamed.

`MKPinAnnotationView` is *deprecated* in iOS 15, but you can still use it. Deprecation just means it isn't recommended that you use it for new apps, it may go away in the future and you can't expect any enhancements.

`MKMarkerAnnotationView` has been available since iOS 11, so unless your app is targeting iOS 10 or earlier you can simply switch to using it instead of `MKPinAnnotationView`

Comment: I don’t want to use deprecated code, but thanks for the hint that `MKMarkerAnnotationView` has been available earlier (+1). So the Xcode 13 warning „'MKPinAnnotationView' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: renamed to 'MKMarkerAnnotationView‘“ is misleading.  But the general problem remains.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner It isn't misleading. First A exists; then there is usually a period during which A and its prospective replacement B exists; then, sometimes after many years of coexistence, A is deprecated; and then finally, some time later even than that, A is removed.

Comment: @matt I consider "renamed to ..." as misleading when it was not renamed but replaced.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Ah. Take it in two parts. Part 1: "It was deprecated." You: "Oh golly, what do I do now?" Part 2: "Fear not: there's a replacement name." So you see, they are helping you, not misleading you.

Comment: "Renamed" is a poor choice of words. It should say "replaced by" or similar.

Comment: On a side note, if you used .pinTintColor to change the color of an MKPinAnnotationView, you have to use .markerTintColor to change the color of an MKMarkerAnnotationView.